# Global Unit test setup and teardown across multiple test packages in golang

Tags: go, testing

I am wondering is there a way to configure global test setup and teardown across multiple test packages in golang?

I am having a situation where I need spin up test cotainers for entire test session and clean it up after all the tests executed.